# How to efficiently save and retrieve position of element in backend DB?

Tags: flutter, backend, sqflite

I am implementing a simple todo app in flutter and sqflite as DB (sql). I have implemented listView using **ReorderableListView** (ie: elements can be dragged vertically), I want to save the position in DB whenever dragging takes place. I have done using it changing each element in DB after a certain index, but it is not efficient, because if there is thousands of todo then updating positions of majority of todos in DB is not efficient and also if using any kind of backend (ie: firebase). Is there a way to implement it efficiently ? Thanks.

**My code:**

```
Future<void> updateMultiple(List<Todo> rows, int start) async {
Database db = await instance.database;
final batch = db.batch();
for (int i = start; i < rows.length; i++) {
  final td = rows[i];
  td.setIndex(i);
  batch.update(table, td.toMap(),
      where: '_id = ?', whereArgs: [rows[i].id]);
}
await batch.commit(noResult: true);
}
```

Note: Above method is called each and every time dragging takes place.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Continuously calling a database is not the best pattern to perform these activities since you are accessing the disk. Things become even worse if you are using a remote database. To keep the update fast enough the best option is to update data using a local state and then update the database only in specific situations (Widget disposed, app lifecycle changed, etc)